# How to get rid of .d..t (timestamp change) outputs from rsync?

Tags: rsync

when I compare two directories with rsync app, I can see there are many outputs about timestamp change. For example:

```
$ rsync --dry-run -avh -i --delete --size-only --checksum --stats dir1/ dir2/

...
...
.d..t...... 3com/
.d..t...... RTL8192E/
.d..t...... acenic/
.d..t...... adaptec/
.d..t...... advansys/
.d..t...... amd/
.d..t...... amdgpu/
.d..t...... ar3k/
.d..t...... ar3k/1020201coex/
.d..t...... asihpi/
.d..t...... ath10k/

...
...
```

I just want to see any file changes when their md5sums are not the same. I don't want to see any timestamp change. How can I avoid those `d..t` outputs?

Thanks a lot.

**Edited:**

I thought `--size-only` would imply `--no-times`, but it doesn't. Thank @BowlOfRed very much for the answer. So the final working command is:

```
rsync --dry-run -avh --no-times -i --delete --checksum --stats dir1/ dir2/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying (via the `-a` flag) that you want timestamps to be preserved on all files/directories, so it's reporting that those changes will happen.

Either don't give the `-t` flag (which is coming in via `-a`), or add `--no-times` after that on the command line.

`rsync` will now not use time as a criteria to check if updates are necessary, and it will not attempt to update if the only difference is timestamp.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. After removing `--size-only`, adding `--no-times` and changing the command to `rsync --dry-run -avh --no-times -i --delete --checksum --stats dir1/ dir2/`, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Those look like directory timestamps, which you could ignore by piping the output through `grep -v '/$'`.

If you want to be absolutely precise use a more complete RE, which matches only the `d..t` sequence for directories, and then ignores only those lines

```
rsync … | grep -v '^\.d\.\.t\.\.\.\.\.\. .*/$'
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to the already accepted answer, I'd use -r --size-only instead of -a (which expands to -rlptgoD).

You're avoiding timestamp differences, so you're skipping the 't' of those (rlptgoD). Using -r instead of -a assumes you don't need the others (lpgoD).

Where: l (small L) is symlinks, p is permissions, g is group, o is owner and D which is equivalent to --devices --specials

Your question is about needing to avoid timestamp differences and your example given includes checksum, but I'll assume you don't need to do the checksum (which takes much longer). So an example could be :

```
rsync -rhinv --size-only --progress --delete --stats
```

You have -ahiv in your example so I assume you know what they do. The -n is shorthand for --dry-run.

Off-topic: I've never used --stats before. I just tried it and it adds about a dozen line summary to the rsync output. Good to know. I would personally continue to use --stats if I'm expecting a lengthy list of output. Otherwise not.